# Может кто объяснить,что за условие в строке с оператором if?

Tags: javascript, строки, функции, include, indexof

Не понятно,что подставляется в методе includes. По заданию функция проверяет содержится ли в передаваемой ей строке  буквы в алфавитном порядке,если нет возвращает undefined

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
    let alf='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let len =str.length;
    let start=alf.indexOf(str[0]);
    for(let i=start;i<=start+len;i++){
      if(!str.includes(alf[i])){
        return alf[i];
      }

    }
     
    
 return undefind;
}

fearNotLetter("abce");


fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno");// should return "i".
fearNotLetter("stvwx");// should return "u".
fearNotLetter("bcdf");// should return "e".
fearNotLetter("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");// should return undefined.
```

Comment: А вы знаете про отладчик?

Comment: Слыхал о таком,но там во вкладке  Console  у меня почему-то ошибка:Unexpected identifier

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если
! - отрицание 
str - строка
includes - содержит
alf[i] - текущая буква в цикле который перебирает строку alf

Таким образом получается

> Если str не содержит alf[i]

Comment: чего-то сразу не сообразил,теперь ясно.Спасибо